# How to map a region with angle $\theta$ and squeezed by 2 half-lines into upper half-plane

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider 2 half-lines that start from the origin of the complex plane and go to infinity. We only know that the region bounded by these 2 half-lines has angle $\theta$. My question is there a conformal map that maps it to the upper half-plane?

My original idea was that if I can know the angle of one half-line with respect to the real line, then I can first rotate it and then by some $z^{\alpha}$ to resize the region to be the upper half-plane. But the thing is I only know the angle between these 2 half-lines.

Any help on this？ Thanks.

Comment: You want a specific function that works in every case where your sector of angular size $\theta$ occurs at an arbitrary heading from the origin?!

Comment: Yes, if it's possible, I hope there's a function that can depend on $\theta$. If it's too complicated for this general case, just assume $\theta=\frac{\pi}{3}$